# Sympy lambdify array with shape (n,)

Tags: sympy

I have the following 'issue' with sympy at the moment:

I have a symbolic expression like `M = matrix([pi*a, sin(1)*b])` which I want to `lambdify` and pass to a numerical optimizer. The issue is that the optimizer needs the function to input/output numpy arrays of shape `(n,)` and specifically NOT `(n,1)`.

Now I have been able to achieve this with the following code (MWE):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
a, b = sp.symbols('a, b')
M = sp.Matrix([2*a, b])
f_tmp = sp.lambdify([[a,b]], M, 'numpy')
fun   = lambda x: np.reshape( f_tmp(x), (2,))
```

Now, this is of course extremely ugly, since the reshape needs to be applied every time `fun` is evaluated (which might be LOTS of times). Is there a way to avoid this problem? The `Matrix` class is by definition always 2 dimensional. I tried using `sympy`'s `MutableDenseNDimArray`-class, but they don't work in conjunction with lambdify. (symbolic variables don't get recognized)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to convert a matrix to a nested list and take the first row:

```
fun = sp.lambdify([[a, b]], M.T.tolist()[0], 'numpy')
```

Now `fun([2, 3])` is `[4, 3]`. This is a Python list, not a NumPy array, but optimizers (at least those in SciPy) should be okay with that.

One can also do

```
fun = sp.lambdify([[a, b]], np.squeeze(M), 'numpy')
```

which also returns a list.

In my test the above were equally fast, and faster than the version with a wrapping function (be it `np.squeeze` or `np.reshape`): about 6 µs vs 9 µs. It seems the gain is in eliminating one function call.

Comment: This is really helpful! There only seems to be a bug with the (1,1) case: if I use np.squeeze(M, axis=1) for a (1,1) Matrix, the result has shape () instead of the expected (1,).

Comment: Also the second options seems to return lists, too and not np.array. (using sympy 1.1.1 and numpy 1.14.3)

Comment: Right on both counts. The edge case of `(1, 1)` can be fixed with `np.squeeze(np.array(M), axis=1)` but the fact that we don't get a NumPy array anyway suggests the first version is better anyway.