# How can I get a 'broadcasted' (m,n) array from a (m,)-valued Sympy Matrix which should take a (n,) numpy array as an argument?

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

I have the following case:
I defined a Sympy Matrix (Vector) which is a function of parameters in some, but not all elements. So e.g. take

```
from sympy import *
a = Symbol('a')
M = Matrix([a,0])
```

Now I want this to be a function which takes numpy arrays as an element, I used lambdify for this. Actually I want M to be a row vector so I did the following which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156059/sympy-lambdify-array-with-shape-n).

```
funcM = lambdify([a], M.T.tolist()[0], 'numpy')
```

Passing a list or an array, e.g. `[0,1]` to this new function gives me:

```
In [596]: funcM([0,1])
Out[596]: [[0, 1], 0]
```

Actually I want the function `funcM` to work in a way that the output is

```
[[0,1],[0,0]]
```

so that the output contains two column vectors, one for each input value in the list, so the column with 0,0 for the input 0 and the column 1,0 for the input 1.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I find `print(funcM.__doc__)` to be helpful in seeing what the resulting `numpy` code is like.

Comment: The code for your function is `([a, 0])`.

Comment: `lambdify` does relatively simple lexical translation to python/numpy.  If you don't know how to do something, like building the desired array with `numpy`, trying to get there via `sympy` is not likely to work.  `numpy` `broadcasting` controls the interaction of 2 or more arrays; it does not come into play when constructing arrays from smaller pieces.

Comment: Okay thanks, that helps me to understand where exactly the problem is. Still I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: While I could write a `numpy` expression that concatenates a row of 0s to a 1d array, I have no idea how this could be generated from a sympy expression.